# Conectar GeneXus a API rest de NetSuite

Tags: api, rest, genexus

les consulto, saben cómo hacer una conexión desde GeneXus a NetSuite? Para consumir un api rest? resulta que me contrataron para editar un portal ya creado, y tengo versión trial por lo que no puedo ver el contenido del mismo, por esos quiero saber bien el proceso antes que me proporcionen la versión de paga. Tengo el código que trae el Json de NetSuite en c# y debo pasarlo a GeneXus para hacer las conexiones. Ayuda!

Comment: Ayudaría si agregaras el código a la pregunta.

Comment: El backend de netsuit hasta donde tengo entendido deja disponible un conjunto de API rest para poder consumirlo. Siendo ese el caso, podes consumirlo desde genexus haciendo las llamadas a dichos endpoints sin problema. Igual si podes dar mas info concreta del caso seria de ayuda para darte una respuesta mas acorde.

Comment: El problema es que tengo que usar la autenticación "HMAC-SHA256" para la pagina, y tengo el código para crear esta autenticación en c#(descargada de un git y adaptada), y debo transcribirlo a genexus pero no estaría sabiendo por donde arrancar

Answer (score 0):

Buen dia Joel.

Si, se puede consumir un servicio Rest sin problemas.
Creas una variable del tipo HttpClient y seteas lo parametros de la siguiente forma:

```
&HTTPClient.Host = URL de host
&HttpClient.BaseUrl = Base Url o nombre de la aplicación
&HTTPClient.Timeout = 60
&HTTPClient.Secure = 1
```

Después los cabezales los agregas así:

```
&HTTPClient.AddHeader('Content-type','application/json')
&HTTPClient.AddHeader('Charset','utf-8')
&HTTPClient.AddHeader('Connection', 'close')
```

Por último agregas el body:

&HTTPClient.AddString(&body.ToJson())

y para ejecutarlo es:
&HTTPClient.Execute(HttpMethod.Post, !'NombreDelMetodo')

Para ver si se consumió correctamente es:
&HTTPClient.ErrCode = 0 And  &HTTPClient.StatusCode = 200

y la respuesta del servicio la ves:
&HTTPClient.ToString()

Comment: Si Si, se como hacer las peticiones al Api Rest, lo que no estaría entendiendo es como realizar la autenticación con "HMACSHA256" en genexus, porque tengo el código de autenticación en c#, pero no logro transcribirlo a genexus

Comment: Entiendo que HMACSHA256 es un algoritmo de encriptación, si lo que necesitas es encriptar el Json antes de enviarlo para "hablar el mismo idioma" te paso un link donde explica como encriptarlo en función del algoritmo de encriptación que necesites: https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?33457,CryptoHash+data+type

Comment: Claro necesito hacer esta encriptación, genexus lo hace por su cuenta o debo crear el algoritmo que concatene las partes del url?

Comment: En la url que te pase explica como encriptar un string, lo que te recomiendo es que lo pruebes desde el postman y si es un servicio REST común con un body encriptado con el algoritmo HMACSHA256, encripta el body en https://www.devglan.com/online-tools/hmac-sha256-online y proba si asi funciona, en Genexus replicas la logica de armar el body y previo a enviarlo lo encriptas con 

&CryptoHash.Algorithm = CryptoHashAlgorithm.HMACSHA256/
&resultingstringHMACSHA512 = &CryptoHash.Compute(&text,&key)

Comment: Gracias! Me sirvió un montón! ahora consulto, cuales son los headers a encriptar?

Answer (score 0):

Estoy en lo mismo que tu y no he podido conectarme por Genexus, el problema que tengo es que no llego al valor de signature.
No se como encriptar en Genexus, lo que probe fue este comando pero tampoco llego.

&CryptoHash.Algorithm   = CryptoHashAlgorithm.HMACSHA256 //&CryptoHash is of CryptoHash type.
&signature          = &CryptoHash .Compute(&BaseString, &Key)

Tendras la solución???
Gracias desde ya
MPF